# Text to Speech - Not working in background

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have implemented a very basic TTS in my Android app which seems to work well when the app is running in the foreground, but it doesn't play when in the background. It waits until the app returns to the foreground and plays what is in the queue. How do I achieve this for my GPS tracking app which needs to provide track feedback while the display is off?
My main class implements:
 TextToSpeech.OnInitListener

I queue the tts with:

```
ttsProgressStr = "Time " +
                timeStringForVoice(trackingTimeMillis);
ttsEngine.speak(ttsProgressStr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
```